# PHP: Calling a 'setup' abstract method from an abstract class constructor; good or bad design?

Tags: php, design-patterns, constructor, abstract-class

I'm trying to decide the design pattern for a class structure I'm working with and I'm torn on the best way to implement the setup of the classes.

One approach calls an abstract setup function in the constructor of the abstract class, the other is to override the constructor in the classes which extend the abstract class.

A couple of (contrived and simplified) examples to outline my thinking:

***Calling abstract method***

```
<?php

abstract class VehicleAbstract implements VehicleInterface
{
    protected $_wheels;

    private $_engine;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $engine)
    {
        $this->setupWheels();

        $this->_engine = $engine;
        $this->_engine->setWheelsToDrive($this->_wheels);
    }

    public abstract function setupWheels();
}

class Car extends VehicleAbstract
{
    public function setupWheels()
    {
        $this->_wheels = array(
            "frontL",
            "frontR",
            "backL",
            "backR"
        );
    }
}
```

**Pros:**

- When implementing the concrete class it's obvious the method
  "setupWheels" needs to be created.
- Only the setup code needs to be written inside the "setupWheels"
  method.

**Cons:**

- When implementing it may not be immediately obvious what
  "setupWheels" needs to do without looking through the parent class.
- Someone new looking at the extended class may not realise the method
  is called when the class is created.

---

***Overriding constructor***

```
<?php

abstract class VehicleAbstract implements VehicleInterface
{
    protected $_wheels;

    private $_engine;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $engine)
    {
        $this->_engine = $engine;
        $this->_engine->setWheelsToDrive($this->_wheels);
    }
}

class Car extends VehicleAbstract
{
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $engine)
    {
        $this->_wheels = array(
            "frontL",
            "frontR",
            "backL",
            "backR"
        );

        parent::__construct($engine);
    }
}
```

**Pros:**

- When viewing the concrete class immediately obvious when the wheel data is being setup.

**Cons:**

- When extending the abstract class it may be missed that the wheel
  data needs to be setup at all.
- While implementing the new constructor need to remember to call the
  parent constructor.
- Need to call parent constructor in correct position in new constructor.

Comment: Have you looked at interfaces? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php They work similar to your first idea, only it will output errors if they do not add the required functions.

Comment: Interfaces wouldn't solve this problem, they can't have concrete methods like an abstract class (which the hypothetical vehicle class would have).